# How can I use relative paths with .Net Interoperability in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, f#

System: Windows with WSL Ubuntu 20.04

I have the following minimal c file:

```
int one () {
  return 1;
}
```

Which I compile with: `test.c -shared -o test.out`

Then I have an X-Unit project with the file:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

module Interop =
  [<DllImport(@"../c_code/a.out", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
  extern int one()

module Program = 
    let [<EntryPoint>] main _ = 
        printf "Hello F# XUnit\n"
        Interop.one () |> printfn "One: %A"
        0
```

This runs normally with `dotnet run InteropFsCheck.fsproj`. There are no errors, it executes as expected.
The test file looks like:

```
module Tests
open System
open Xunit
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
module Interop =
  [<DllImport(@"../c_code/a.out", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
  extern int one()
  
[<Fact>]
let ``My test`` () =
    let a = Interop.one()
    Assert.True((a=1))
```

This gives me and error `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

If I change the DllImport to `<DllImport(@"/mnt/c/Users/Flippie/Documents/GIT/ProofofConcept/InteropFsCheck/c_code/test.out", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]`, it works.

Is there any way I can use the relative paths instead? I want to use github actions with it later, so I expect I will have problems with abslute paths.

---Background---

I am trying to use .Net interoperability to unit test a C library that I am writing/updating. The library is gnu89, and upgrading to c99 is not an option.

I currently use [Unity](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/), but it doesn't support property based testing. [Theft](https://github.com/silentbicycle/theft) is c99, and I have not had much success using it.

Thus I want to use .net interoperability with FsCheck to run my tests.

Comment: This has little to do with interop. When you run a unit test, the executable is the test runner, so relative paths are relative to the test runner. This is a common problem with all unit tests and tools - how do you load test data from a local folder for example?

Comment: Using `@"../c_code/a.out"` will fail in production too. When you run your application, it will look for `a.out` in the parent folder, which probably won't exist. Make sure `a.out` is included as content in the project and copied to the output and use just `a.out` as the path. This way, both your app and the test runner will look for the library in the current working directory

Comment: Okay, that works. Not the solution I wanted, but it makes sense. If you convert this to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I never trust the current working directory, because some piece of the tested code, or even your tools, will perhaps at some point during your development fiddle with the current working directory. Then your tests can fail. Instead, find a reliable way to get the path of the test runner.